# Get a list of all Java reserved Keywords

Tags: java, regex, keyword, reserved-words

I'm looking for a way to retrieve all the saved keywords in Java into some kind of data structure. For example: "for, while, if, else, int, double, etc."

I need to do a name validation on a string, to be specific, I need to make sure it does not equal to any java keywords.

Is there a specific way of retrieving all the keywords into one data structure? or do I need to just build a regex string with all these keywords in it : "for|while|if|..." and try and match my string against it?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords

Comment: @Kabulan0lak yeah, I know of the list, I want to know if there is any way to get the list as some kind of ADT, such as ArrayList or just an array - dynamically (through some lines of code)

Comment: Nop there isn't any method. Copy-past http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html this in a file and read your file. It is what I would do.

Comment: [JLS 7, 3.9 Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9), [JLS 8, 3.9 Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)

Comment: A rare requirement; do you by any chance mean **JavaScript** instead of Java? (`function` being a keyword <-> `double`.) For HTML safeguarding.

Comment: @JoopEggen No, its Java

Comment: @Kabulan0lak yeah, I was saving that as a last resort, but yeah I might do that in the end, Thx

Comment: @user475680 Turns out we're all idiots and Java has had an API for this since way back in version 1.6!  Could you update the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141029/1965404 ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [axis.apache.org](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel/1.4/org/apache/axis2/util/JavaUtils.java#JavaUtils.isJavaKeyword%28java.lang.String%29)

Basically, **Pre-Sort** the keywords and store it in an array and using **Arrays.binarySearch** on your keyword for the good'ol **O(logn)** complexity

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class MainDemo {
        static final String keywords[] = { "abstract", "assert", "boolean",
                "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const",
                "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "extends", "false",
                "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements",
                "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
                "new", "null", "package", "private", "protected", "public",
                "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super", "switch",
                "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "true",
                "try", "void", "volatile", "while" };

        public static boolean isJavaKeyword(String keyword) {
            return (Arrays.binarySearch(keywords, keyword) >= 0);
        }

        //Main method
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(isJavaKeyword("void"));

        }

    }
```

**Output:**

True

---

Alternatively, as  users @typeracer,@holger suggested in the comments,
you can use `SourceVersion.isKeyword("void")`  which uses  `javax.lang.model.SourceVersion` library and `Hashset` Data structure internally and keeps the list updated for you.

Comment: …and storing them in a `HashSet` would give you `O(1)` complexity without even the need to pre-sort them.

Comment: Great suggestion,i forgot about Hashset!

Comment: I actually ended up implementing your suggestion a while back, but I just discovered a native API for this that's apparently existed since Java 1.6!  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141029/1965404

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised that no one suggested [javax.lang.model.SourceVersion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html) yet, because it's actually been around since Java 1.6.

If you need to check whether some string is a reserved keyword, you can just call:

```
SourceVersion.isKeyword(str)
```

And if you really need the full list of the reserved keywords, you can obtain it from the source code of that class:

```
private final static Set<String> keywords;
static {
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    String [] kws = {
        "abstract", "continue",     "for",          "new",          "switch",
        "assert",   "default",      "if",           "package",      "synchronized",
        "boolean",  "do",           "goto",         "private",      "this",
        "break",    "double",       "implements",   "protected",    "throw",
        "byte",     "else",         "import",       "public",       "throws",
        "case",     "enum",         "instanceof",   "return",       "transient",
        "catch",    "extends",      "int",          "short",        "try",
        "char",     "final",        "interface",    "static",       "void",
        "class",    "finally",      "long",         "strictfp",     "volatile",
        "const",    "float",        "native",       "super",        "while",
        // literals
        "null",     "true",         "false"
    };
    for(String kw : kws)
        s.add(kw);
    keywords = Collections.unmodifiableSet(s);
}
```

---

**Caution**: the above source code is from **Java 1.8**, so *don't just copy & paste from this post* if you're using a different version of Java.  In fact, it's probably not a good idea to copy it at all — they made the field **private** for good reason — you probably don't want to have to keep it up-to-date for every new Java release. But if you absolutely must have it, then copy it from the source code in your own JDK distro, keeping in mind that you might have to manually keep updating it later.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct API method. As an alternative, you  take them in an array and check the entered keyword   matches in the array if keywords.

```
 public static String[] keys= {  "new",..... }
```

then

```
 for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {  
            if (input.equals(keys[i])) {  
               // TO DO
            }  
        }
```

Comment: I would probably use `HashSet` and its `contains` method but array will also do the trick.

Comment: @Pshemo Agreed with you :) basic idea is to traversing in a container.

Comment: Actually, turns out there is a direct API method; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141029/1965404

Answer (score 1):

OK So since there is no automatic way of doing it, I will create a text file consisting of all the keywords :
[List of Java Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

And then at runtime go over the file, inserting each keyword into an array, or arraylist (or regex string) and check use that data structure when I check for name validity.

Thanks to everyone