# Quick Access to java keywords

Tags: java, keyword

Is it possible with the Java System Library to get all Java keywords like for,while, etc. in a HashTable etc.

Or do i need to write them all down by myself?

I want to scan a String for the keywords.

Comment: i don't knew of that kind of lib , but if you are doing manually here is some nice things , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265110/get-a-list-of-all-java-reserved-keywords

Comment: This sounds like a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the array of all the Java reserved keywords (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265110/get-a-list-of-all-java-reserved-keywords) and keep being updated from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)):

```
String keywords[] = { "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", 
    "char", "class", "const", "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "extends", 
    "false", "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", 
    "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native", "new", "null", "package", 
    "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super", 
    "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "true", "try", 
    "void", "volatile", "while"
};
```

You have to navigate to the library where is Hashtable class using the `JAVA_HOME` system variable.

```
System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
```

The `java.util.Hashtable` (and others) is located at `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/rt.jar` library.

You have to find a way to extract the package, find the required file, decompile it and read lane by lane (using f.e. Regex). I recommend you to start reading answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906786/how-to-read-a-class-file-from-an-extracted-jar-file).

Unfortunately, there is **NO** other way.

Comment: I don’t think that the OP wanted to scan the class `Hashtable` for keywords (otherwise, processing the already compiled class from the `rt.jar` would be entirely pointless). As I understood it, they wanted the keywords stored in a `Hashtable` or similar structure (and apparently, an array is fine too). Starting with Java 9, I’d recommend `Set.of(…)`. Note that your array lacks `enum`. Further, it’s worth noting that formally, `null`, `true`, and `false` are not keywords but literals. Depending on the use case, it may still be useful to include them, e.g. they are not allowed as identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

A list of Java keywords can be found in the Java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

With a list like this, you can create a String array that you can search.